# Find the PDF of $\frac{X}{Y^{2}}$ for the given intervals of the random variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**Question:** Assume we have two  independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ and they are respectively uniformly distributed in intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,5)$. Find the PDF of $\frac{X}{Y^{2}}$.

---

I have seen questions alike, but it was always given a function and $X+Y$ or $X-Y$ was wanted. I have no idea what to do with this problem. I would be pleased if someone could help me with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider $Z = \frac{X^2}{Y}$ and $P(Z \le z)$ - you might want to consider different intervals for $z$ - and then differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method of transformations:

Let $U=\frac X{Y^2}$ and $V=Y^2$, so that $X=UY^2=UV$ and $Y=\sqrt V$. The Jacobian determinant for this change of variables is

$$\det J = \begin{vmatrix}X_U & X_V \\ Y_U & Y_V\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}V & U \\ 0 & \frac1{2\sqrt V}\end{vmatrix} = \frac{\sqrt V}2$$

Then the joint density of $U$ and $V$ is

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}\left(x(u,v), y(u,v)\right) \cdot \det J = \frac12 \sqrt v\, f_{X,Y}(uv,\sqrt v)$$

$X$ and $Y$ are independent, so $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$ and you can find $f_{U,V}$ from there. Then you can get the marginal density of $U=\frac X{Y^2}$ by integrating the joint density of $U$ and $V$ with respect to $v$ over the support.

$$f_U(u) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{U,V}(u,v) \, dv$$